# Looking for PHP redirect code for a form mailer script

Tags: php, forms, email

I am using a form from "ReusableForms" and it is working fine but due to Bootstrap version conflicts, I cannot include the form in my Bootstrap 4.2.1 webpage, I have to just work with the form as a "on it's own" page which is fine but after the form is submitted and the success message shows up, I'd like the form to redirect to the home page of my site. Here is the code for the handler and for the html form:

```
<form method="post" id="reused_form" >
                    <button class="button-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <div id="success_message" style="display:none">
                    <h3>Submitted the form successfully!</h3> 
                    <p> Eric will get back to you soon. </p>
                </div>
                <div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; "> <h3>Error</h3> Sorry there was an error sending your form. </div>
```

php code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
Tested working with PHP5.4 and above (including PHP 7 )

 */
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;


$pp = new FormHandler(); 

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['Name','Email'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('Email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('Message')->maxLength(6000);


$pp->requireReCaptcha();
$pp->getReCaptcha()->initSecretKey('');

$mailer = $pp->getMailer();

//Using SMTP account
$mailer->IsSMTP();
$mailer->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mailer->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mailer->Host       = "";
$mailer->Username   = "";
$mailer->Password   = "";

$mailer->setFrom('', 'Camp Bay Form');


$pp->sendEmailTo(''); // ← Your email here

echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

I have been searching the internet trying other code in the handler, and I've tried the hidden redirect input and nothing is working, I assume cuz of how the handler code is written doesn't match others out there..

I expect it is something real easy to be added in the handler code, I just need to know what to put in there to get the redirect to work!

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific with your question. From what I can tell, I see that you need a destination in the HTML form.

Add action="example.com/index.php" to  in your HTML.

```
<form method="post" id="reused_form" action="/handler.php">
<button class="button-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="success_message" style="display:none">
<h3>Submitted the form successfully!</h3> 
<p> Eric will get back to you soon. </p>
</div>
<div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; "> <h3>Error</h3> Sorry there was an error sending your form. </div>
```

Although I do not suggest that. It would be better to have everything in the same file:

````
    ```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST)) {
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    /*
    Tested working with PHP5.4 and above (including PHP 7 )

     */
    require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

    use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;


    $pp = new FormHandler(); 

    $validator = $pp->getValidator();
    $validator->fields(['Name','Email'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
    $validator->field('Email')->isEmail();
    $validator->field('Message')->maxLength(6000);


    $pp->requireReCaptcha();
    $pp->getReCaptcha()->initSecretKey('');

    $mailer = $pp->getMailer();

    //Using SMTP account
    $mailer->IsSMTP();
    $mailer->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mailer->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mailer->Host       = "";
    $mailer->Username   = "";
    $mailer->Password   = "";

    $mailer->setFrom('', 'Camp Bay Form');


    $pp->sendEmailTo(''); // ← Your email here

    $output = $pp->process($_POST);
}
    ?>
    <form method="post" id="reused_form" >
                        <button class="button-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
    <?php echo $output; ?>
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

See jQuery Form submission handling : http://reusableforms.com/d/a/contact-form-bootstrap

I think you have to had redirection in javascript like this :

```
<script>
$(function()
{
  function after_form_submitted(data)
  {
    if(data.result == 'success')
    {
        $('form#reused_form').hide();
        $('#success_message').show();
        $('#error_message').hide();

        setTimeout(function () {
          window.location.href = "/"; // Your redirection here
        }, 2000);
    }
    else
    {
        // Your code here, see documentation

    }//else
}
</script>
```